# Do I have to log error if I raise exception anyway?

Tags: python, logging

I have following code snippet:

```
def require(name: str) -> Any:
    logger.info(f"Recipe required: {name!r}")

    entries = []
    for entry in iter_entry_points('recipe'):
        if entry.name == name:
            logger.debug(f"Found entry for recipe {name!r}: {entry} at {entry.dist}")
            entries.append(entry)

    if not entries:
        logger.error(f"Recipe not found: {name!r}")
        raise RequireError(f"could not find recipe {name!r}")

    if len(entries) > 1:
        dists = []
        for entry in entries:
            logger.error(f"Ambiguous recipe: {name!r} defined in {entry.dist!r}")
            dists.append(f'* {entry.dist!r}\n')

        raise RequireError(f"ambiguous recipe {name!r}! conflicting distributions:\n{''.join(dists)}")

    entry, = entries

    logger.info(f"Recipe found: {name!r}")

    ...skipped
```

As you can see, I raise errors when I don't meet certain conditions. Because I follow "fail fast" principles, this actually kills the app. Does it make any sense to additionally **log** these things before raising?

Comment: Of course you don't have to handle every exception. You handle them only if you can, say, recover from the error. You log it if you want to do something with the log.